# Magento 2: File path for changes in css

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new to magento 2 and I am making css changes in luma theme on below path.

But after content deployment I lost my css changes.
Please help me in that.

/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css

Answer (score 1):

> You should not edit/modify files within pub/* or vendor/* directory.
>   Pub is for deployment and vendor is for default structure, which you
>   override via your template or custom modules

**Instead:**

- create a new theme inside app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{yourTheme}/.
  You can use Blank or Luma theme
- You can also create new theme which inherites from Blank (inheritance
  is defined within theme.xml). If you are already using some theme
  then skip this step.
- edit .less within your theme so the changes stay visible and don't
  get replaced when clearing the cache or upgrading the system.
- Use grunt to compile your .less into deployment files.
- You can also setup sourcemaps to pin point your styling within the
  theme .less files so you can be more productive.

**if you want to override  only css file then you don't need to compile it. so follow above steps , change your css and  clear the cache. it will worked**.

Comment: Avoid editing luma or blank theme,after content deploy or module upgrade it will reset to default,so extend luma theme  or create new one